How to add an htaccess rule for a search page so that it will work with and without query parameter
Is it possible for me to add an htaccess rule for a search page so that it will work with and without query parameter. I ll add the example below
Actual file is www.mysite.com/search.php
Below 2 links should work for me

www.mysite.com/search/loremipsum

www.mysite.com/search/?query=loremipsum


The rule I have added on htacess is given below
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php? [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)$ search.php?query=$1 [L]

Any help will be much apprecited

Where do you put the .htaccess file?

@KIKOSoftware In my php root folder where search.php resides

Why is the RewriteCond checking for an empty query string gone now, after your edit? Without that, the first rule will rewrite to search.php? regardless of whether a query string existed on the originally requested URL, or not.

Unfortunatelu, I could not crate a folder. Is it possible to achive only by adding rule on ,htaccess

For starters, I would make the name of the GET parameter that your script expects, match that of the 2nd URL. Otherwise, you will have to extract the value from the query string, to "rename" the parameter, and that is just extra effort that could be easily avoided.

@CBroe Actually i am new to htacess, Could you please add as an answer with example, This will be much appreciated

If you're happy with changing your script to expect a parameter named query instead of title, then RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L] and RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)$ search.php?query=$1 [L] should do the job (without any additional RewriteConds.)

Your current .htaccess rules are almost there, but you need to tweak them slightly to achieve the desired behavior.
here is a suggestion:
RewriteEngine On

# Match URLs without query parameters
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L]

# Match URLs with query parameters
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]

the QSA flag at the end means "query string append", which ensures that existing query parameters are preserved when adding title=loremipsum.

Thank you let me check, Also WIth this rule I can add more params as follows ?
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?othertitle=$1 [L,QSA]

@Ajith using the exact same pattern twice, that makes no sense to begin with.

Ohh okay..let me try with the given answers then. Thank you

If I request /search/foobar, you have no way of telling, whether that was meant to be a search for a title, or othertitle. So you need to use different URL patterns for these two cases to begin with - like f.e. /search/title/foobar and /search/othertitle/foobar. Then you could match each with a dedicated rule, and rewrite them accordingly.

/search/foobar and /search/othertitle/foobar would also be possible. Since you are currently only matching search terms that do not contain a /, the order of the rules could still be either way around. Or, if you eventually want to allow the search terms to contain / as well, it would still work, if you matched the second case first, and then the more general one. (Only searching for the actual title othertitle/foobar would then not be possible any more, because that would be interpreted as a search for an othertitle with the value foobar then.)

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)$ /search.php?query=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/search\.php\?query=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [R=301,L]

